# How do I validate a web servers certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, web, certificate

I have an interesting problem.  Our team manages a large number of Load Balancers and Web servers in AWS.  The certificate management blows chunks, so I am trying to add a module to the [trycorder](http://trycorder.stiv.com) that will hit every SSL protected endpoint and check the certificate expiration date,  as well as any other certificate details that may be useful.
  Found an example based on the following, but it fails with an error about being unable to establish trust. I don't care about trust, I just need to check out the certificate being used.

```
Based on help recieved, I have gotten this far, but failing because I dont understand how to recover the data from the delegate within the context of the calling function.  I need the function to return the certificate.  Can this be done? (email code if it is too large to megastiv@stiv.com. Thanks for your help!!!!

    public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string urltocheck)
    {
        X509Certificate2 ToReturn = new X509Certificate2();
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urltocheck));
            var gimme = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                ToReturn = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
                return true;
            };

            ServicePoint svcPoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(urltocheck));
            return ToReturn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return ToReturn;
    }
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ServicePointManager` to allow any certificate and you have a chance to inspect it with the `certificate` argument:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
                {
                        //do stuff with certificate...
                        return true;
                };
```

It sounds like you have a valid use case for this, of course you almost never want to blindly trust just any certificate.

Comment: I have seen that before,  but that bit of code does not make it clear to me how I invoke it.  Sorry for my ignorance. Looking for a function that takes a URL as an argument, and returns the certificate, or data from the certificate.

Comment: Just run that any time before making your service calls. ServicePointManager is used behind the scenes so you only need to do this once and it will run that callback always.

Comment: I have seen that before,  but that bit of code does not make it clear to me how I invoke it.  Sorry for my ignorance. Looking for a function that takes a URL as an argument, and returns the certificate, or data from the certificate.  Was able to get the //do stuff with certificate working, but not able to figure out how to pass data in that code to my return value. Obviously I am new to delegates.... :(

Comment: To make this more painful, since I am running through a whole pile of instances to check, I cant have delegates stomping on each other. Was hoping the delegate would exist within the context of the function that called it, but appears it may exist for multiple iterations which then overwrite each other.

Comment: Updated question with copy of current function. Currently, though the delegate processes like I want, it does not actually pass the certificate out to the function so it is returned to the program calling it.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. You run this one time only, at the start of your program, for instance. Any service call will invoke the callback, you can do anything in there that you can do in a method. You don't need an inline delegate, you can point it to any method with a compatible signature.

Comment: Thanks CC.  Its working to get the cert, but I cant seem to pass the data back out of the callback.
  Its like the callback executes in some magical fairyland, and I can set the value of ToReturn to the certificate in the callback code, but when the callback is finished, and I actually try to return ToReturn it does not have the value I set in the callback.  How do I access the values generated inside the callback? Do I need to have some "WaitForDelegate" thingy before returning?   So close!   Appreciate all your assistance!

Comment: How odd. Maybe you can try using HttpWebRequest. [It also has a callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) which may not be in fairyland.

Comment: I am going to call this "Answered", thanks Crowcoder!   The issue with returning a value is another problem which I shall attempt to figure out or get answered elsewhere.